# C#: Find Unknown Character in a String

Tags: c#, string, difference

I have `*` strings and I want the only unknown character and its position. For instance, I want character '`a`' or '`b`' or '`c`' or anything (unknown) and its positions in the strings below:

```
1) "******a***" // I want 'a'
2) "b****"      // I want 'b'
3) "*******c"   // I want 'c'
```

The strings are always have `*` characters. Sometimes I have '`a`', sometimes '`n`', sometimes '`x`', and so on. I don't know what character coming inside stars (`*`).

How can I do this in `C#`?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want all `a`, `b`, `c` characters position? What do you mean by _unknown character_ exactly? It is for only `*`? Would be better if you clarify your question..

Comment: Where was the problems when you tried to achieve that?

Comment: I've just edited the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
// the string
var str = "******a***";

// the character
var chr = str.Single(x => x != '*');

// the position
var pos = str.IndexOf(chr);
```

Please be aware that `Single` will throw an exception in case nothing found. Use it only when you're certain there's one (and only one) unknown character. If you're not sure use `SingleOrDefault` and check for `Char.MinValue`.

Answer (score 1):

With regex

```
    public static char GetUnknownChar(string s, char knownChar)
    {
        const string mask = "[^{0}]";
        var match = Regex.Match(s, string.Format(mask, knownChar));
        return match.Value[0];
    }
```

with LINQ:

```
    public static char GetUnknownChar(string s, char knownChar)
    {
        return s.First(c => c != knownChar);
    }
```

with multiple known chars:

```
    public static char GetUnknownChar(string s, IEnumerable<char> knownChars)
    {
        var knownSet = new HashSet<char>(knownChars);
        return s.First(knownSet.Contains);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the positions

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
string foo = "**x*";
char[] knownChars = new char[]{'*','!','?'};
int i = 0;
for (; i < foo.Length; i++)
    if (knownChars.Contains(foo[i]))
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more primitive way:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FindUnknown("******a***");
        FindUnknown("b****");
        FindUnknown("*******c");
    }

    private static void FindUnknown(string myString)
    {
        var tag = '*';
        var unknown = ' ';
        var unknownIndex = -1;

        var currentIndex = 0;
        foreach (var character in myString)
        {
            if (character != tag)
            {
                unknown = character;
                unknownIndex = currentIndex;
                break;
            }
            currentIndex++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Unknown character: {0}", unknown));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Unknown character index: {0}", unknownIndex));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively novel yet understandable LINQ solution:

```
var strings = new[] {"******a***", "b****", "*******c"};

foreach (var str in strings)
{
  var prefix = str.TakeWhile(c => c.Equals('*'));
  var postPrefixIndex = prefix.Count();
  var unknownCharacter = str[postPrefixIndex];

  Console.WriteLine("{0} at {1}", unknownCharacter, postPrefixIndex);
}

// a at 6
// b at 0
// c at 7
// Press any key to continue . . .
```